# Ruby Object Initialize with Optional Arguments

Tags: ruby, parameters, initialization

How can I code an initalizer() method to form instance variables (empty or otherwise), then iterate through a set of args to set instance variables?

This is what I am thinking:

```
def initialize(*p)
  @sid                      = "123asdf654"
  @token                    = "abc123"
  @bert                     = "1192875119"
  @me                       = "4165551212"
  @media_url                = ""
  @message                  = ""

  args.each do |k,v|
    instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) unless v.nil?
  end
end
```

I want to have the ability to set known instance variables (shown here), then iterate through args and either update the values of chosen instance variables, or create new ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to do that you need to accept not an array of arguments (*varargs* style) like you've specified, but either an options hash or the new *keyword-args* style option.

The classic approach:

```
def initialize(attributes = nil)
  attributes and attributes.each do |k,v|
    instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) unless v.nil?
  end
end
```

The new keyword-arguments approach:

```
def initialize(**options)
  options.each do |k,v|
    instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) unless v.nil?
  end
end
```

You can also subclass [OpenStruct](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/OpenStruct.html) to get behaviour like this for free.

Keep in mind there's a new option style that might be a good mix of both these approaches:

```
def initialize(sid: '123', token: '...', ...)
  @sid = sid
  @token = token
  # ...
end
```

You can specify defaults for the named keyword arguments.

Comment: That last one seems the most legit due to how direct it is, if I have defaults.

Comment: @Rich_F It's the way I'd suggest going about it if you're not concerned about any sort of Ruby 1.9 compatibility. As that's been end-of-lifed, you should be good.

Comment: More concerned about abstract applications, or general approach to tossing new properties at the object at instantiation instead of using the attr_accessor.  One step onCreate better than two.

Comment: Try it out. This is something introduced in Ruby 2.0 that hasn't been used nearly as much as it should.